# to obtain the value from a datatable to a listbox in c#

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, listbox

I have a label, data table and a list box. 
Table has columns [BUS_NAME] and [SEAT NUMBER].
And The label displays the bus name and 
when the button is clicked

the values in the column [SEAT_NUMBER] whose [BUS_NAME] values are same as that of the text in the label should be listed in the list box.

i used this

```
       for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Bus_NAME"].ToString();

            if (lbl_busname.Text == textBox1.Text)
            {

                    listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Seat_Number"].ToString()); 
             }
            }
```

But this is not working. Thanks in advance..

Comment: comapring busname with busid :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to compare bus name not id. So change this line

```
textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Bus_ID"].ToString();
```

to

```
textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["BUS_NAME"].ToString();
```

you can also improve this by

```
 DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("BUS_NAME = '"+lbl_busname.Text+"'";
```

and loop on dr without applying any check like

```
 foreach(DataRow d in dr)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(d["Seat_Number"]));             
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Bus_NAME"].ToString();
      }

        if (lbl_busname.Text == textBox1.Text)
        {

                listBox1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["Seat_Number"].ToString()); 
         }
```

else u can use the same for the following

```
foreach(DataRow d in dr)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(d["Seat_Number"]));             
}
```